# Python: How to group unsorted list of dictionary into new list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, grouping

I have a list like this:

```
table=[{'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i1'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i2'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i4'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i5'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i3'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i7'}]
```

I want to group that list into a new list like this:

```
newtable=[{'device':'a','iface':['i1','i2','i4','i3']},{'device':'b','iface':['i5','i7']}]
```

I have tried to use defaultdict from collections module but the result is not what I expected.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

> here what i have done:

```
from collections import defaultdict
table=[{'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i1'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i2'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i4'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i5'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i3'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i7'}]
newtable=defaultdict(list)
for row in table:
    newtable[row['device']].append(row['iface'])
newtable=list(newtable)
```

and I lost from here.
So sorry for my English.

Comment: What did you try with `defaultdict`? It's pretty well suited to the problem.

Comment: *"the result is not what I expected"* - what did you get instead? Please add a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code and explain exactly what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it - Just using `defaultdict` might not be enough. You might have to process it a little further (just make sure you use better variable names :) ):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> xx = defaultdict(list)
>>> table=[{'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i1'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i2'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i4'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i5'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i3'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i7'}]
>>> for tab in table:
...   xx[tab['device']].append(tab['iface'])
... 
>>> xx
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['i1', 'i2', 'i4', 'i3'], 'b': ['i5', 'i7']})
>>> yy = dict(xx)
>>> yy
{'a': ['i1', 'i2', 'i4', 'i3'], 'b': ['i5', 'i7']}

>>> new_table = []
>>> for a in yy:
...   new_table.append({'device': a, 'iface': yy[a]})
... 
>>> new_table
[{'device': 'a', 'iface': ['i1', 'i2', 'i4', 'i3']}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': ['i5', 'i7']}]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. this answer is more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

I chose to collect the items in the list `table` by their device-value into a map, and keep extending the `iface` list when new items of the same device are being iterated:

```
table=[{'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i1'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i2'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i4'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i5'}, {'device': 'a', 'iface': 'i3'}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': 'i7'}]
new_table = []
tmp_map = {}
for itm in table:
    map_itm = tmp_map.get(itm['device'])
    if not map_itm:
        tmp_map[itm['device']] = {'device':itm['device'] ,'iface': [itm['iface']]}
    else:
        tmp_map[itm['device']]['iface'] = [itm['iface']]+ map_itm['iface']
print tmp_map.values()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'device': 'a', 'iface': ['i3', 'i4', 'i2', 'i1']}, {'device': 'b', 'iface': ['i7', 'i5']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a dictionary. Then you can't have a link between a key and a value in the list. If you want something similar to a dictionary you can do two loops, one for key and the other for values, and then include that into a list. You can ask for something like System.out.println(key + ":" + value)